# Required image size when using pytorch pretrain model to predict

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, image-size, pre-trained-model

I used the ResNet-18 from PyTorch to predict an image. I've read that `(224, 224)` is the image size for this model. But when I tried to resize the image to `(124, 124)` or `(324, 324)`, it's still working. Anybody can tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of ResNet variants on PyTorch comes with an [`AdaptiveAvgPool2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d.html) layer before the fully connected layer, ensuring that the output features are always of the correct shape for the fully connected layer, regardless of input size.

In addition, the input size of `224x224` is recommended to prevent suboptimal amounts of padding.

Comment: Is there a variant which is optimized to arbitrary image size input? Surely without a pretrained weights, but at least the same formation of the net.

Comment: Do you mean optimized as in "trained on"?

Comment: You wrote about `suboptimal amounts of padding`. Is there a model with no such issues? When I say model I mean the architecture, not the weights.

Comment: I do not have a fully exhaustive knowledge of the literature, but I refer you to: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/388859/is-it-possible-to-give-variable-sized-images-as-input-to-a-convolutional-neural